# Не понимаю что сравнивается в alert(1 && 0)

Tags: javascript

Я вообще верстальщик ещё пока, не ругайте много. К концу рабочего дня не могу понять, что к чему приводится вот здесь:

```
alert( 0 && 1 ); // 0
alert( 1 && 2 && 3 ); // 3
alert( null || 1 || 2 ); // 1
```

И почему результат такоей, а не иначе. Только привык к сравнениям в C#, а тут JS преподносит сюрпризы.

Comment: булевые оператора в яваскрипте возвращают один из операндов, например, `&&` первый элемент который приводится к _false_, или последний в выражении

Comment: По логике здесь должен возвращаться false, но возвращается 0. Почему не 1?

Comment: И почему в следующем примере возвращается 3, соответственно?

Comment: _булевые операторs в яваскрипте возвращают один из операндов_

Comment: @Олег Вам же сказали почему.

Comment: Хм, наверное, потому что "alert( false && true ); // false"

Comment: посмотрите [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

Comment: вообще говоря - это не сравнение, а [логические операторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Практически во всех языках логические операции `and` и `or` - ленивые. JavaScript - не исключение. Это означает, что при вычислении `a && b` вычисляется сначала `a`. Если оно истинно, операция просто возвращает результат вычисления `b`, в противном случае - эквивалент `a` (м.б. другой эквивалент `false`), при этом `b` НЕ вычисляется ВОВСЕ.

Для операции `a || b` все происходит аналогично - если `a` истинно - возвращается `a` (при этом `b` не вычисляется), в противном случае `b`.

На этом основаны конструкции типа:

```
do_some_operation() == 0 || abort_program();
```

в качестве эквивалента записи

```
if (do_some_operation() != 0) abort_program();
```

Если `do_some_operation()` вернет не 0 (что-то пошло не так) - выполнится `abort_program()`, в противном случае, то что после `||` просто игнорируется. Подобные идиомы очень широко распространены в `perl`, да и в JS тоже.

Поэтому, при вычислении `0 && 1` сначала "вычисляется 0, а т.к. он эквивалентен `false`, то он и возвращается, независимо от того, что там справа от `&&`. Попробуйте, кстати, `alert( 0 && alert("hello"))` и `alert(0 || alert("hello"))`, это здорово проясняет ситуацию.

```
1 && 2 && 3 // то же, что (1 && 2) && 3, вычисляем 1, т.к. истинно, вычисляем 2, т.к. тоже истинно (1 && 2 == 2), возвращаем 3.
```